# Creating window intervals of the positions in R

Tags: r

I am creating an interval list of the positions, by window 4 and step 1.

```
pos <- subs$variable
intervals <- paste0(pos[seq(1, n, by=1)],":", pos[seq(4, n, by=1)])
```

intervals I get are:

```
[1] "92:107"  "101:120" "106:132" "107:136" "120:140" "132:146" "136:147" "140:152" "146:166" "147:167" "152:174"
[12] "166:186" "167:187" "174:189" "186:204" "187:228" "189:229" "204:107" "228:120" "229:132"

subs <- structure(list(variable = c(92, 101, 106, 107, 120, 132, 136, 
140, 146, 147, 152, 166, 167, 174, 186, 187, 189, 204, 228, 229
), covMean = c(11355.658, 11450.079, 11479.711, 11495.132, 11612.053, 
11580.158, 11421.684, 11288.105, 11278, 11239.763, 11236.895, 
10425.526, 10386.789, 10233.816, 9523.132, 9503.316, 9450.158, 
8532.763, 7795.368, 7656.895), emboss = c(1.3717151, 1.3828546, 
1.3880071, 1.3879077, 1.3959816, 1.3830276, 1.3724465, 1.363247, 
1.337794, 1.3334625, 1.3097811, 1.2826296, 1.2811749, 1.2676601, 
1.2193303, 1.2136416, 1.2044259, 1.1649542, 1.1163399, 1.1125204
)), row.names = c(56L, 62L, 65L, 67L, 77L, 82L, 87L, 95L, 97L, 
114L, 119L, 133L, 154L, 156L, 169L, 173L, 186L, 190L, 212L, 214L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Why it starts iterating from the beginning, I want it to stop at the last position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq(1, n, by=1)` and  `seq(4, n, by=1)` are not of same length, the values are recycled. Try :

```
n <- length(pos)
intervals <- paste(pos[1:(n-3)],pos[4:n], sep =':')
intervals

# [1] "92:107"  "101:120" "106:132" "107:136" "120:140" "132:146" "136:147" "140:152" "146:166"
#[10] "147:167" "152:174" "166:186" "167:187" "174:189" "186:204" "187:228" "189:229"
```